# Как можно считать кол-во реакций на сообщении, и сравнить их

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Есть бот для голосований. Голосование он начинает, а вот не выходит сделать подсчёт реакций. Вот пример как должно было работать:

[image]

Всё робит, кроме подсчёта, никто не знает как можно посчитать реакции? Мой нерабочий код:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
    for emoji in message:
        emoji = payload.emoji
        if emoji == '✅':
            global Y
            Y += 1
        elif emoji == '❌':
            global N
            N += 1
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
    for emoji in message:
        emoji = payload.emoji # реакция пользователя
        if emoji == '✅':
            global Y
            Y -= 1
        elif emoji == '❌':
            global N
            N -= 1
if Y > N:
    Result = 'Принято'
elif Y == N:
    Result = 'Отказано(Да = Нет)'
else:
    Result = 'Отказано'
@Bot.command(pass_context= True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def endvote(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Окончено голосование.', description = 'Результат: ' + str(Result), colour=discord.Color.purple())
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) # Возвращаем сообщение после отправки
Y = 0
N = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать в классе переменную `message_id` и в ней сохранить id сообщения для голосования. Далее найти это сообщения и просто взять количество реакций с этого сообщения (не будет необходимости считать самому). Минимальный пример:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

message_id = 0 # Переменная для сообщения голосования

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startvote(ctx, content):
    channel = ctx.channel
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Голосование.', description='Голосуем за ' + str(content),
                                  colour=discord.Color.purple())
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    global message_id # Если используется класс, то необходимо создать в классе переменную
    message_id = message.id # Сохраняем id сообщения для голосования

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def endvote(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id) # Ищем сообщение
    # Фильтруем реакции, чтобы остались только нужные
    resactions = [reaction for reaction in message.reactions if reaction.emoji in ['✅', '❌']]
    # Превращаем результат голосования в строку (вычитаем 1 из количества, значение по умолчанию)
    result = ''
    for reaction in resactions:
        result += reaction.emoji + ": " + str(reaction.count - 1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Результат.', description='Итог голосования: ' + str(result),
                                  colour=discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Результат:

[image: Результат работы]

Если необходимо просто получить количество реакций, то можно воспользоваться таким способом (пример из кода выше):

```py
# Функция endvote
reactions = {'✅': 0, '❌': 0}
for reaction in resactions:
    reactions[reaction.emoji] = reaction.count - 1
```

В итоге получим словарь, где количество реакций можно найти по emoji: `reactions['✅']`.